# gcc (4.8.3) sanitizer options to blacklist functions

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I am compiling my code on gcc 4.8.3. I have enabled `-fsanitize=address` option. But my program exits during startup throwing global buffer overflow error in 3rd party library code. So i am trying to skip sanitizer for this function (or caller function). I tried `__attribute__((no_sanitize("address")))` but compiler throws warning that `‘no_sanitize’ attribute directive ignored` 
even tried `-fsanitize-recover=address` but recovery doesn't seem to be supported on address. 
Can any one help me with how to make my program continue after first error, or black list function to skip sanitizing?

**EDIT**

```
template <class T>
void __attribute__((no_sanitize_address)) OID_CB<T>::Init(s8_t* name, s8_t* data, u32_t entryNum, u32_t start,  u32_t end, u32_t entrySize, bool ViewFlag, bool WholeTableFlag)
{
        strcpy(mName,name);
        mName[strlen(name)]='\0';
        mData         = data;
        mEntryNum     = entryNum;
        mStart        = start;
        mEnd          = end;
        mEntrySize    = entrySize;
        mIsView       = ViewFlag;
        mIsWholeTable = WholeTableFlag;
}


==22247== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x000002ca57bf at pc 0x1020cc2 bp 0x7ffdd93b7070 sp 0x7ffdd93b7060
READ of size 1 at 0x000002ca57bf thread T0
    #0 0x1020cc1 in OID_CB<causeCodeMgr>::Init(char*, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, bool) /xxxx/xxxx/common/causeCodeMgr/../../../xxx/oam/include/cm_interface.h:457
    #1 0x1020cc1 in CMI<causeCodeMgr>::addOID(char*, unsigned long long, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, bool) /xxxx/xxx/common/causeCodeMgr/../../../xxx/oam/include/cm_interface.h:1289

    0x000002ca57bf is located 45 bytes to the right of global variable '*.LC670 (causeCodeMgr.cpp)' (0x2ca5780) of size 18
  '*.LC670 (causeCodeMgr.cpp)' is ascii string 'causeCodeInternal'
0x000002ca57bf is located 1 bytes to the left of global variable '*.LC671 (causeCodeMgr.cpp)' (0x2ca57c0) of size 26
  '*.LC671 (causeCodeMgr.cpp)' is ascii string 'internalCauseCodeToAction'
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow /xxxx/rhel_7_1_x86_64/xxxx/common/causeCodeMgr/../../../xxxx/oam/include/cm_interface.h:457 OID_CB<causeCodeMgr>::Init(char*, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, bool)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x00008058caa0: f9 f9 f9 f9 00 07 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 06 f9 f9
  0x00008058cab0: f9 f9 f9 f9 00 03 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 04 f9 f9
  0x00008058cac0: f9 f9 f9 f9 00 00 02 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 00 06 f9
  0x00008058cad0: f9 f9 f9 f9 00 00 00 00 02 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9
  0x00008058cae0: 00 00 06 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 00 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9
=>0x00008058caf0: 00 00 02 f9 f9 f9 f9[f9]00 00 00 02 f9 f9 f9 f9
  0x00008058cb00: 00 00 00 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 07 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9
  0x00008058cb10: 00 00 00 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 04 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9
  0x00008058cb20: 00 03 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 07 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9
  0x00008058cb30: 00 00 02 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 07 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9
  0x00008058cb40: 00 04 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 00 01 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9 f9
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap righ redzone:     fb
  Freed Heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried **attribute**((no_sanitize("address"))) but compiler throws
>   warning that ‘no_sanitize’ attribute directive ignored

I'm afraid GCC does not support this syntax (there's even [a bug in their Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78204)). You should be able to use `no_sanitize_address` though (read about it in [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)).

> even tried -fsanitize-recover=address but recovery doesn't seem to be
>   supported on address.

This only appeared in GCC 6.

Comment: Yes, like you suggested no_sanitize_address worked for test program with normal function. But didn't take effect for template member function. I couldn't find any example for template functions

Comment: @Nasir I suggest you post minimal example which illustrates your problem. This may or may not be a compiler bug.

Comment: I missed to compile one library with the attribute enabled. @yugr your answer solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message (and some others) and I figure out the following BUGS:

starter: I switched BACK from opensuse Tumbleweed (~2024) to Leap (~2020) and a couple of BUGS show up.

1. one problem was that I have to reinstall the "autoconf/automake/libtool" scripts with "autoreconf -fvi"
2. another problem was that the "AC_PROG_CC" and "AC_PROG_CXX" have to be BEFORE the "LT_INIT" because the "libtool" depend on the proper CC & CXX variable to select the compiler BUT the AC_PROG_CXX does NOT set the CXX and thus the CXX setup in "libtool" choose some unusable things